# Recursion only generating one pair. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, backtracking

I'm attempting to create permutations from an input list. My recursion fails and only brings me back a single list, where there should be multiple.
I'm uncertain as to whats wrong with my logic - new to recursion.

```
class Solution:
    def permute(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        answer, perm = [], []
        self.dfs(nums, answer, perm)
        return answer

    def dfs(self, nums, answer, perm):
        if not nums:
            answer.append(perm)

        for ind, ele in enumerate(nums):
            perm.append(ele)
            nums.pop(ind)
            self.dfs(nums,answer, perm)
```

Expected: [[1,2,3],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[1,3,2],[3,1,2],[3,2,1]]
Actual: [[1,2,3]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be helpful to log out some of the data passing through your solution so you can see exactly what you are doing wrong.  If we log `nums` and `perm` at each step of your code, we get the following:

```
[1, 2, 3]             # nums 0
[]                    # perm 0
[2, 3]                # nums 1
[1]                   # perm 1
[3]                   # nums 2
[1, 2]                # perm 2
[]                    # nums 3
[[1, 2, 3]]           # result
```

All your code currently does it move elements from a list to a sublist containing the original list.  You need to keep track of which elements have been added to the sublist without emptying the original list, and then you can create your desired permutations.  You can still accomplish this with recursion, but adding the functionality of the `set` will make your life a lot easier.

Here is a basic example, which you can adapt as needed:

```
def dfs(data, perm_out=None):
    if not perm_out:
        perm_out = []
    if not data:
        return [perm_out]
    res = []
    for point in data:
        u = {point}
        diff = data - u
        res += dfs(diff, perm_out + [point])
    return res
```

Calling it on your simple input data:

```
i = [1, 2, 3]
u = dfs(set(i))
print(u)
```

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation - your code is very easy to follow. Logically I had assumed that iterations would point to a copy of the object(idk why I had though that). So that makes sense that I am altering the iteration!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that it removes an element from `nums` at each iteration of the `for` loop, and returns the answer once `nums` has been emptied. So with input `[1,2,3]`, first the `1` is appended to `perm` is removed from `nums`, then the same for `2`, then `3`, and once `num` is empty, `perm = [1,2,3]` which is appended to `ans` and returned.

Note that you can simply use the `permutations()` method from `itertools` to generate permutations from a list:

```
import itertools

input_list = [1,2,3]
permutations = list(itertools.permutations(input_list))
print(permutations)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your code follows the format of a code problem from a coding challenge I am assuming you want to know why your solution doesn't work instead of a different solution using python built in functionality.

For reference you could do this in two lines:

```
import itertools
result = list(itertools.permutations([1, 2, 3]))
print(result)
```

The issue while working `list`s is that they all pass by pointers. Here is a recursive solution. I added some prints to make it easier to see what is happening.

```
class Solution:
    def permutation(self, s):
        # if our list is only one element
        # then nest our list and return it
        if len(s) == 1:
            return [s]

        perm_list = [] # resulting list
        for element in s:
            # Grab elements other then the one we currently have
            remaining_elements = [x for x in s if x != element]

            # Permute on the remain elements
            # a list is returned
            print("Calling with", remaining_elements)
            permutations = self.permutation(remaining_elements) # permutations of sublist

            for perm in permutations:
                # combine our current element with the permuation
                perm_list.append([element] + perm) 
        print("Returning ", perm_list)
        return perm_list
```

Comment: That makes sense - I didnt realize they pass by pointers rather than the actual object. But it makes sense knowing that. Thanks!